# NuGet adds System.Runtime to web.config on every update causing run-time error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, nuget

I have a solution with multiple projects, two of them being MVC5 web apps.
Every time I update *any* nuget package in *any* project, the mvc apps' web.config is modified, adding the following:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This causes runtime error:

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies
>   should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the
>   Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]

If I remove this entry from the web.config, everything works OK, it's just annoying to remember to do it every time.
Any ideea why is this happening?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am encountering the same issue now.

Comment: How about a year later? Did you find any solution to this? The same thing keeps happening to me too

Comment: Stopped looking :)

Answer (score -1):

so this came up for me after I had manually added a link to system.runtime.dll at location 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll`

Removing this fixes this problem but the reason I added it in the first place was because I needed a portable nuget package that required that dll to build. So I ended up leaving it in place and manually deleting it all the time. :(